# implementing my wp_query using $wpdb class

Tags: query, wpdb

I have two custom post type `doctors` and `location`. Each `doctors` post relates to a `location` post using Advanced Custom Fields relationship field.
I want to write my `WP_Query()` code using `$wpdb` class and pure SQL. How can I do this?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'doctors',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key'       => 'location', // name of custom field
        'value'     => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    ) ),
);

$testimonials = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Can you just take the SQL generated by the WP_Query?

Comment: for paginating ajax function 
  $all_blog_posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'doctors' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page ) );

Comment: where to use meta_key?

Comment: you can use WP_Query for AJAX and pagination. look here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: how?
i didn't find

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what you want from this request and what is it for. You should clarify that to get the most accurate answer.

Anyway, if you want to write a pure SQL request you can't use WP_Query but need to use `$wpdb->get_results` instead, as mentionned by @hadimahoor. Here is a request to get a list of all doctors with their location.

```php
global $wpdb;

// Pure SQL
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT p.ID, post_title as doctor, p2.ID as location_id, p2.post_title as location
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.ID AND m.meta_key = 'location'
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts p2 ON p2.ID = m.meta_value
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND ...");
$doctors = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

And here is the simplest solution to get the doctors list by location :

```php
// Get doctors by location
$doctors = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'doctors',
    'meta_key' => 'location',
    'meta_value' => $location_id
]);
```